Schrödinger equation for particle at rest: initial gaussian vs. initial binomial
Assuming a standard initial Gaussian wave packet for a free particle at rest (at $x=0$ and $t=0$), we all know how to use the Schrödinger equation to derive the time evolution of its probability amplitude $\psi(x,t)$. Sure, the initial Gaussian distribution hypothesis is very convenient, allowing an exact solution to be derived in a straightforward way. However, by pretending to be picky, we might find ourselves uncomfortable with an initial assumption, the Gaussian packet, embedding from the start a probability amplitude $\neq 0$, no matter how tiny a value, at distances that even light would not have had time to reach after freeing our particle.  Recalling that a Gaussian may represent quite a good approximation of a symmetrical binomial distribution, I have been searching, to no avail, whether anybody has ever studied the possibility of solving the Schrödinger equation under the assumption that the initial probability distribution is binomial instead of Gaussian. In other words, denoting by $\Delta$ the distance beyond which we wish the initial probability $|\psi(x>\Delta,t=0)|^2=0$, and by $\delta$ the size of identical discrete intervals (chosen in order that $\frac{\Delta}{\delta}$ is integer), the initial probability distribution may then be written as (where we define $x_n = n \delta$ )
$$ |\psi(\pm \, x_n, \, t=0)|^2 \, = \,\frac{\left(\frac{\Delta}{\delta}\right)\,!}{2^{\frac{\Delta}{\delta}}\,\left(\frac{|x_n|}{\delta}\right)\,! \, \left(\frac{\Delta}{\delta}-\frac{|x_n|}{\delta}\right)\,! }  $$
whereby the size of $\delta$ can be made arbitrarily small, according to how "smooth" we wish the initial discrete binomial distribution to be.
Finding a solution would entail to first derive the amplitude $\psi(\pm \, x_n, \, t=0)$ whose module square is the binomial distribution above. If that amplitude could then be express as a linear combination of the amplitudes for each one of the $x_n$ intervals (just simple "amplitude rectangles" of base $\delta$ and height $\sqrt{|\psi(x_n)|^2}$ ? and what about the phase ? ), then the solution to the Schrödinger equation would simply be the sum of the time evolution for each individual "rectangle". Unfortunately, myself I was unable to go any further, getting nowhere ... let alone trying to transfer the same sort of approach to the Dirac equation.

This wavefunction is quite "wild" from the point of view of the Schödinger equation, since the free-space Hamiltonian contains second derivatives (with respect to position) and your thing isn't even differentiable. That said you should be able to make some progress by Fourier transforming a "rectangle" (the answer is a $\operatorname{sinc}$ function, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Tables_of_important_Fourier_transforms). The free space Schödinger equation is very simple when expressed in terms of momentum.

The mean momentum being 0 does not mean that particle is "at rest". The Gaussian is not an eigenstate of momentum, and so it does not have a definitive momentum / speed associated with it

@BioPhysicist I am not sure I understand how your comment relates to my question.

It's relevant to the post since the expression is in the post. It doesn't solve the problem, but if I was solving the problem I would write an answer, not a comment.
